# Optimize index for multi field ordering with mixed direction

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I'm trying to optimize a MySQL table for faster reads. The ratio of read to writes is about 100:1 so I'm disposed to sacrifice write performances with multi indexes.

Relevant fields for my table are the following and it contains about 200000 records

```
CREATE TABLE `publications` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  -- omitted fields
  `publicaton_date` date NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  -- these are just attempts, they are not production index
  KEY `publication_date` (`publication_date`),
  KEY `publication_date_2` (`publication_date`,`position`,`active`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;`enter code here`
```

Since I'm using Ruby on Rails to access data in this table I've defined a default scope for this table which is

```
default_scope where(:active => true).order('publication_date DESC, position ASC')
```

i.e. every query in this table by default will be completed automatically with the following SQL fragment, so you can assume that almost all queries will have these conditions

```
WHERE `publications`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY publication_date DESC, position
```

So I'm mainly interested in optimize this kind of query, plus queries with publication_date in the WHERE condition.

I tried with the following indexes in various combinations (also with multiple of them at the same time)

```
`publication_date`
`publication_date`,`position`
`publication_date`,`position`,`active`
```

However a simple query as this one still doesn't use the index properly and uses filesort

```
SELECT  `publications`.* FROM `publications`  
WHERE `publications`.`active` = 1 
AND (id NOT IN (35217,35216,35215,35218)) 
ORDER BY publication_date DESC, position
LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: publications
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 34903
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Some considerations on my issue:

- According to MySQL documentation a composite index can't be used for ordering when you mix ASC and DESC in ORDER BY clause
- `active` is a boolean flag, so put it in a standalone index make no sense (it has just 2 possible values) but it's always used in WHERE clause so it should appear somewhere in an index to avoid Using where in Extra
- `position` is an integer with few possible values and it's always used scoped to `publication_date` so I think it's useless to have it in a standalone index
- Lot of queries uses `publication_date` in the where part so it can be useful to have it also in a standalone index, even if redundant and it's the first column of the composite index.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your are mixing sort orders in the order by clause. You could invert your position **(inverted_position = max_position - position)** so that you may also invert the sort order on that column.

You can then create a compound index on **[publication_date, inverted_position]** and change your order by clause to **publication_date DESC, inverted_position DESC**.

The **active** column should most likely not be part of the index as it has a very low selectivity.